# Dagger doesn't generate Adapter for TestModule

Tags: android, robolectric, dagger, annotation-processing

How can I make apt process test source files?
When I have following setup I'm getting exception:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class info.korzeniowski.walletplus.test.module.TestDatabaseModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.`
and class `TestDatabaseModule$$ModuleAdapter` is not generated while `DatabaseModule$$ModuleAdapter` is generated correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

#### build.gradle:

```
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'info.korzeniowski.walletplus'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Dagger
    def daggerVersion = '1.2.+'
    apt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
}
```

#### ./src/main/java/info/korzeniowski/walletplus/module/DatabaseModule.java

```
package info.korzeniowski.walletplus.module;

@Module(
    ...
)
public class DatabaseModule {

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public DatabaseModule(WalletPlus application) {
        databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(application, DatabaseHelper.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public DatabaseHelper provideDatabaseHelper() {
        return databaseHelper;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

#### ./src/androidTest/java/info/korzeniowski/walletplus/test/module/TestDatabaseModule.java

```
package info.korzeniowski.walletplus.test.module;

@Module(
    ...
    includes = DatabaseModule.class,
    overrides = true
)
public class TestDatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public DatabaseHelper provideTestDatabaseHelper() {
        return new DatabaseHelper(Robolectric.application, null);
    }
}
```

#### RobolectricTest.java

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    List<Object> modules = new ArrayList<Object>();
    modules.add(new DatabaseModule((WalletPlus) Robolectric.application));
    modules.add(new TestDatabaseModule());
    ObjectGraph.create(modules.toArray()).inject(this);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `apt` configuration is only for the main sources. You must also declare the annotation processor to run for test sources since it is a separate invocation of `javac`.

You can do so using a similar syntax:

```
androidTestApt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks you Jake. Also `androidTestApt` configuration is available since android-apt 1.4 version.